# Can you ignore a value in a DLL?

Tags: asp.net

In Grrr.Premium.Google.GoogleGeoCode, the baseUrl is set to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/, which is failing because it needs to be https.

Is it possible to modify the code below to ignore the value in the DLL and define it here?

```
            Grrr.Premium.Google.GoogleGeoCode encode = new Grrr.Premium.Google.GoogleGeoCode();
            encode.Query = "json?key=#######&address=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtAddress.Text.Trim() + " " + txtCity.Text.Trim() + " " + drpState.SelectedValue + " " + txtZip.Text);
            encode.GeoCode();
```

I feel like this must be possible, and easy, but I can't figure it out. :(

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The Google API docs say that using https is optional (although recommended). A trivial test just showed that using http: returns identical results to https:. Are you sure this is the reason you're having a problem? What exact symptoms are you seeing?

Comment: I don't think it's optional anymore, and I can tell you https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=###&address=60657 with https works while the same URL with http does not.

Comment: Actually, yeah, google returns it with the error: `"error_message" : "Requests to this API must be over SSL. Load the API with \"https://\" instead of \"http://\".",`